# Why does Ryan Ask this to Jack?

Tags: bioshock

Heavy spoiler for Bioshock :

> When Ryan meets with Jack, he explains to Jack who he is. Ryan then hands Jack the golf club and orders Jack to kill him, using the "would you kindly" command. Jack obeys, and proceeds to beat his father to death.
>  
>  Why does Ryan ask Jack to do this, instead of asking him something else, like "Would you kindly go get stepped on by a Big Daddy?"?

Comment: A man chooses, a slave obeys.

Comment: @Nick What do you mean, He wanted to make his point, even if it cost him his live? Please detail this in a full answer.

Comment: @Nick I should have asked "Would you kindly detail this in a full answer?"

Comment: The real question is why didn't he say: "Would you kindly kill yourself?" or "... go away" or "... kill Fontaine". Maybe that would have overridden the already standing instruction to kill Ryan.

Comment: @bitmask That what mean by "something else", but would you kindly up-vote this?

Comment: @DavRob60: Dang, in my eager to read the answer I forgot. Or do I just think that to justify me obeying? Existential dilemma!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While you cannot say for certain what Ryan's motivations were, his repeated use of the phrase "A man chooses, a slave obeys." implies he was hoping you would prove yourself to be worthy of being his son and choose to resist your programming. If you were not able to resist then you were merely a slave. In that case Fontaine had already won, and so Ryan took the only option left to him and choose the method of his execution.

Comment: Yes. Note that Fontaine already used the trigger to force Jack to kill Ryan. The command was already issued.

Answer (score 4):

While we can only speculate in regards to Ryan's true motivations and intentions, secondary information gives us a further clue as to what Ryan might have been planning.

#### Why did Ryan instruct Jack to kill him?

We know that Jack has been programmed to obey any instruction prefaced by "Would you kindly?". We also know that Jack has been asked to kill Ryan, using this programming; so we know that Jack *is* going to be *actively trying* to kill Ryan, at least, *until he believes this task to be complete*.

We also know that Ryan is the sort of character that highly regards *personal choice*. In other words, given the choice of dieing *on Fontaine's word* or dieing *on his own word*, Ryan would *always* pick dieing on his own word, hands down.

#### Why did Ryan want to die?

This still does not tell us why Ryan wanted to die; there is speculation that Raptures great failure had led him to the choice of *suicide*, but there *is* another explanation. It is entirely possible that Ryan wanted people to *think* he had died; after all, we *do* see him die. However, *we also see Jack die, many times*. You often do not consider this plot element, especially in a video game; the player dies *a lot*, and there often needs to be a magical way to bring the hero back to some sort of checkpoint; in Bio-Shock, this plot device comes in the form of the *vita-chambers*.

Here is the transcript of a log the player can find, regarding the initial development of the vita-chamber, emphasis mine:

> Initial Deployment, Vita-Chamber/Client Ryan Industries. Stage one is complete. Sinclair and Alexander tried to explain the science to me, but Suchong does not believe them. They keep saying Plasmid reconstruction this and quantum entanglement that, **and then poof, dead people come back to life**. Bullshit! Of course, **Ryan will only allow it to be tuned to his genetic frequencies** for the testing...

In other words, the vita-chambers are specifically tuned to Ryan; the player is only able to "resurrect" because they are his biological son, and thus share genetic frequencies. Following this logic, by allowing (or commanding) Jack to traumatically kill him, he could expect to pop back out of the nearest vita-chamber to carry out his further plans.

#### Wasn't Ryan's vita-chamber turned off?

The vita-chamber in Ryan's office was turned off, but I can not find *any* canonical evidence that vita-chamber operation is linked to any proximity; only that you resurrect at the *nearest* vita-chamber.

We know that any plans to resurrect at a vita-chamber would logically involve convincing Fontaine and Jack that he was dead; after all, if they knew he was alive, they would just keep coming after him. If Ryan resurrected at the vita-chamber *in his office*, chances are very likely that he would run back into Jack, spoiling any potential plan.

Thus, it is possible that Ryan disabled the vita-chamber in his office, with the intention of resurrecting at a vita-chamber *farther away*, permitting him the distance required for a successful escape.